# replace issue with numpy.where with floats and strings

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a column `Annual Salary` in a pandas dataframe that is filled with `float`s. I want to make `Annual Salary` categorical with four categories: the first is all salaries below the first quartile, the second is all salaries from the first quartile to the median, and so on.

This is how I tried to achieve this but it fails on the line with the second replacement.

```
p1 = df['Annual Salary'].quantile(0.25)
p2 = df['Annual Salary'].quantile(0.50)
p3 = df['Annual Salary'].quantile(0.75)
df['Annual Salary'] = np.where(df['Annual Salary'] <= p1, 'cat1', df['Annual Salary'])
df['Annual Salary'] = np.where((df['Annual Salary'] >= p1) & (df['Annual Salary'] <= p2), 'cat2', df['Annual Salary'])
df['Annual Salary'] = np.where((df['Annual Salary'] >= p2) & (df['Annual Salary'] <= p3), 'cat3',      df['Annual Salary'])
df['Annual Salary'] = np.where(df['Annual Salary'] > p3, 'cat4', df['Annual Salary'])
```

Actually, it fails because after the first replacement, the column holds floats and `'cat1'` strings.

How can this be solved in an elegant manner?

Comment: If you want to implement your solution with numpy, you can use `np.select` instead of `np.where`.

Comment: " but it fails on the line with the second replacement" What does this mean? Are you getting an error? Don't make us *guess*. Always provide **the full error message including the stack trace if you are getting an error**. The Python runtime goes to great lengths to provide that, precisely *because* it is good for debugging. Why would you just omit it? Also, please always provide a [mcve]

Comment: look at the result of the `where` before you try any assignments back to the frame.  I suspect it turns all elements into strings.  Test the pieces when something doesn't  work.  Test.  Never assume.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html):

```
df['Cat'] = pd.qcut(df['Annual Salary'], q=np.linspace(0, 1, 5),
                    labels=['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4'])
print(df)

# Output
   Annual Salary Cat
0            143  p4
1            102  p3
2             98  p2
3             75  p1
4            123  p4
5             68  p1
```

Comment: Nice, I like it! Didn't know about `pd.qcut`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're going wrong way. To categorize values all at once use [pandas.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)

```
seq = df['Annual Salary']
bins = seq.quantile([0, .25, .5, .75, 1])
bins.iloc[0] -= 1            # make sure you cover the minimum salary
categorised = pd.cut(seq, bins)
```

By default, `pandas.cut` splits values in left-open ranges, so we need to pass something less than the smallest possible value as the lowest bound. That's why `bins.iloc[0] -= 1`

---

p.s. Let's say you want to do it with `numpy.where`. Then here's the way to do it:

```
q1, q2, q3 = seq.quantile([.25, .5, .75])

categorised = np.where(
    seq <= q1, 'cat1', 
    np.where(seq <= q2, 'cat2', 
             np.where(seq <= q3, 'cat3', 'cat4')))

categorised = pd.Series(categorised, dtype='category')
```